# python3 exchangelib credentials

Tags: python-3.x, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

Im trying to log into an exchangeserver with the exchangelib.
When I try to run the script it gives me an error:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/exchangelib/protocol.py", line 61, in **init**
    assert isinstance(credentials, Credentials)
AssertionError

From what I can understand it says my credential variabel is not of the right type. I have tried both with and without autodiscover enabled. I get the same error.
Here is the relevant code.

```
credents = Credentials(username='domain\\aaa.fh', password= 'password'), 

  config = Configuration(server='domain.aaa.no', credentials= credents)

  account = Account(
          primary_smtp_address='fh@domain.no',
          config=config,
          autodiscover=True,
          access_type=DELEGATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
config = Configuration(
                    server='mail.example.com',
                    credentials=Credentials(username='Domain\username', password='password'),
                    auth_type=NTLM
                    )
account = Account(primary_smtp_address='Emailaddress@domain.com', config=config,
                           access_type=DELEGATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the dreaded Python trailing comma in the first line, which "helpfully" turns your `credents` variable into a tuple of `Credentials`.